# Hoverable Dropdown

Tags: html, css, text, dropdown

I tried to make a Hoverable text, but it gives me a little visual error. I want to make it in this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPCPf.png

but at my website it gives in this way.

http://vestigedayz.com/wqeq

(press on the A from menu on my website)

This is my CODE.

```
   <div class="liste">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>    </ul>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AD</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>

                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>    </ul>  

                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">c</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">d</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">e</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">f</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">g</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">h</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">i</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">j</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">k</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">l</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">m</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">n</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">o</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">p</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">q</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">r</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">s</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">t</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">u</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">v</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">w</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">y</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">z</a></li>    </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

AND THE STYLE CSS

```
.header .liste {background:#ffd564;border-bottom:5px solid #ffecb8;font-size:13px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;padding-left:25px;margin-top:30px;}
.header .liste > ul li {float:left;padding-right:30px;margin:17px 0;}
.header .liste > ul li a {text-decoration:none;color:#1b1b1b;text-transform:uppercase;}
.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
}



.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffecb8;
    min-width: 950px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: I believe `list-style-image` is what you are looking for

Comment: I don't want to add those markers.

if you acces my website, you'll see that it gives a huge visual error 

( A is upside than other letters, and it won't show the dropdown content down, like in the picture)

Comment: this link might be helpfull http://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/

Comment: @EminEryilmaz `list-style: none;` then?

Comment: I'd recommend using flexbox's to achieve that effect, may end up being easier to manage as well as responsive as the screen size goes down.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson  I already have the menu, now I'm just adding a dropdown effect.  Effect works fine, but it won't show that under of menu, and the letter A is showing upside,  it won't leave it back in the line..

Comment: @NalinAggarwal tried, but it won't show the way I want. I want that dropdown to be under of the menu

Comment: @EminEryilmaz my comment was more about the fundamental design choice - your menu may work as is but a flexbox implementation may be easier to build upon, just my 2cents!

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Thank you, but I tried, won't work. I don't even know if the code is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to get A in the right spot you have to put that ul element on the same level as other ul elements (B, C, D etc.) 
So change your list div like this

```
<div class="liste">
  <ul><li><a href="#">A</a></li></ul>
                        <div class="dropdown">

                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AD</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>

                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>    </ul>  

                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">c</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">d</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">e</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">f</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">g</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">h</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">i</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">j</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">k</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">l</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">m</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">n</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">o</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">p</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">q</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">r</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">s</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">t</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">u</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">v</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">w</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">y</a></li>    </ul>  
                    <ul>  <li><a href="#">z</a></li>    </ul>  
            </div>
```

Then find these properties and remove padding left:

```
.header .liste {
    background: #ffd564;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffecb8;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* padding-left: 25px; */
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Then move your opened dropdown down (top: 50px)and change min width to 948px

```
.dropdown-content {
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffecb8;
    min-width: 948px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Then give your liste li padding left:

```
.liste li {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the result: http://screencast.com/t/RD3Akbot

Also, because structure changed you will have to deal with hover.

Here is the code for the hover:

```
.liste ul:hover + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

This says, when you hover over this ul element show next .dropdown div. So all you have to do is add .dropdown sections underneath appropriate ul section. I will add the code snippet below.

```
<ul>  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>    </ul>
<div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AD</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>
<ul>  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>    </ul>
<div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="#">AA777</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AB777</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AC777</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AD777</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Oh, I forgot you have to declare your .dropdown display:none too. So when you hover it will display block.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine, but now letters are from A to O,  not from A to Z.

Beside that, I want to click A or just move the mouse over it and later shall appear the dropdown content.

Comment: Ok, give that padding like this: .header .liste > ul:first-of-type li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

And remove padding here": .header .liste > ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin: 17px 0;
    /* padding-left: 25px; */
}

Comment: http://vestigedayz.com/wqeq/   it shows a little on the right side of the page. 

I want to do something like this. http://i.imgur.com/fg1NTab.png

When I click A, then that dropdown box shall appear. But I don't know how.

Comment: Take the padding off the .header .liste {
    background: #ffd564;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffecb8;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* padding-left: 20px; */
}

Comment: Then add this to your css .header .liste > ul:first-of-type li { padding-left: 20px; }. This is just to move the A to the left a little and not affect the other elements.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

But now, How can I make it to appear only when I press to button A? Because I will copy it to all letters (B, C,D,E ... )

Comment: I updated my answer above to show you how to do the dropdown.

Comment: it works, but it won't allow me to move the mouse on the list.

http://vestigedayz.com/wqeq/#

Comment: Set the height of the li element like this:
.header .liste > ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin: 17px 0;
    height: 55px;***********************add this line
}

Comment: And then add this line so when you hover over the dropdown it stays displaying block: .dropdown:hover {
    display: block;
}

Comment: Yes. Thank you again. :)